# SQLAlchemy hybrid property query self-reference parent attribute

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, python-3.8

I have to following `Node` model who has a `ref_id` FK that could point to itself, and accessing parents through the `associated_refs` attribute:

```
class Node(Base):

    class NodeStatus(enum.IntEnum):
        STATUS_1 = 0
        STATUS_2 = 1

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    status = Column(Enum(NodeStatus))
    ref_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("Node.id", ondelete="SET NULL"))

    ref = relationship(
        "Node",
        foreign_keys=[ref_id],
        uselist=False,
        remote_side="Node.id",
        backref=backref("associated_refs")
    )
```

I want to define a hybrid property by checking if for an instance its parents have the status `STATUS_1`:

```
class Node(Base):
    ...
    @hybrid_property
    def ref_is_status_1(self) -> bool:
        if self.associated_refs:
            return self.associated_refs[0].status == self.NodeStatus.STATUS_1
        else:
            return False

    @ref_is_status_1.expression
    def ref_is_status_1(cls):
        # Help here!
        pass
```

But honestly, I don't know how to do it. Ideally, I would like to be able to query without having to query through SQLA's `session.execute`, which would make it so we can't write unit tests and hinder performance since we've got hundreds of thousands of nodes in the DB!

I tried using expressions with count so I could filter Nodes by those having a count  = 1 and by id but it always returns empty:

```
class Node(Base):
    ...

    @ref_is_status_1.expression
    def ref_is_status_1(cls):
        return select(func.count(Node.id)).where(
                     and_(
                         Node.ref_id == cls.id,
                         Node.status == Node.NodeStatus.STATUS_1
                     )).label("ref_is_status_1")
```

I also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267860/how-do-i-write-a-hybrid-property-that-depends-on-a-column-in-children-relationsh) with a boolean case but it threw a ProgrammingError while due to a `SELECT *` statement without a table being specified:

```
class Node(Base):
    ...

    @ref_is_status_1.expression
    def ref_is_status_1(cls):
        return (
            select([
                case([(exists().where(
                    and_(
                        Node.ref_id == cls.id,
                        Node.status == Node.NodeStatus.STATUS_1
                    )).correlate(cls), True)],
                     else_=False
                     ).label("has_ref_is_status_1")
            ]).label("ref_is_status_1")
        )
```

Comment: What is the relationship between your Node instances, one-to-one or one-to-many ? Also `AStatus` is not defined anywhere, and do you need to define `NodeStatus` in the class or could/should it move to top level ?

Comment: there are lots of undefined variables in the code, the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @ljmc it's a one to many, a node has a single parent node.

Comment: @D.L pretty sure anyone who has worked with SQLA 1.4 understands this, the Base is a declarative_base, ForeignKey is a type of column, etc. What variables confuse you? I'll gladly clarify.